# How prevent performance loss from 301 redirection between non-www to www URL?

Tags: .htaccess, http, http-status-code-301

I have a website which redirect non-www URL to the www version in order to optimize the SEO. However this impact user performance because the non-www request/answer to the server took 500ms after what it will make a new request to the www URL and the website will start loading. This is half a second lost to get the first print of the website if the user type only the domain name without www

Is there a way to prevent this performance loss for the user and yet keep the advantages of an unique entry point for the referencement ? maybe targeting only SEO robots for the redirection ?

Comment: show us the details of how the redirect is implemented please.  you mention .htaccess - is this purely apache environment?

Comment: The performance loss should be a non-issue. If it is taking 500ms for the redirect alone then something is very wrong. (Or you are using a slow/distant server?!) The non-www to www redirect is also an edge case - normal users should not experience this redirect anyway, since all internal links (and indexed URLs) should already be for the canonical URL.

Comment: @DanielFarrell I do not have access to the htaccess yet, I start working for this company next month and I am trying to make a health check of the current website. Maybe I should come back later when I have access to the files ?

Comment: @MrWhite you are right, it should take less than 100ms, but there is another problem related to distant server (customer in Asia and servers in USA) + they use a kind of proxy server for security which is also in USA... its dirty! However I do believe that many users will use the non-www url if they type the address by themself in the bar which can happen because it is a short brand name. I will run some users interview when I arrive and ask a bunch of them to show me how they access the website. As mentioner, maybe I come back when I have access to the htaccess

Comment: Sounds like you could benefit from a CDN, Content Distribtion Network, which provides geographically distributed endpoints that function like a caching reverse proxy.  AWS CloudFront would be one example that, if properly configured, can cache your www redirect as well as the content of your website.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a question of performance, the first thing to do is to make sure that all the internal urls of the website point to the same version (with or without www, http or https)... and then select www as the main one at the server level (from plesk as the default version), or even at the dns zone level in the domain panel.